# Unclear typedef type

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I came across this code and was wondering what it means.
But even after some 15 minutes of looking at it does not make sense to me.

```
template< typename T >
struct Vector4 {
    typedef T Vector4<T>::* const vec[4];
    static const vec constVec;

    //just to have some member instances of T
    T member1, member2, member3, member4;
};
```

So what is the type of constVec?
Please do not just repeat the typedef but explain in common language.

**My notes so far:**

- Why are there two types (`T` and `Vector4<T>`), is this a function pointer?
- What does ::* mean? Take everything from the scope of Vector4?
- Is it a const pointer array? But why the :: then?

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/261920-a-slick-trick-in-c/

Comment: @EddyPronk: Nice to know where those people get that from ^^ Though my source was not from there (but seemingly heavily inspired)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`constVec` is an array of 4 constant pointers to the members of the `Vector4<T>` class which are of type `T`

Note: The members aren't constant, the pointers themselves are.

First, since these are constant pointers, you need to initialize them in the constructor: (I've just noticed the `static` qualifier, so it has to be initialized outside the class, but if it weren't static, you'd need to do that in the initialization list.)

```
template< typename T >
struct Vector4 {
    typedef T Vector4<T>::* const vec[4];
    static const vec constVec;

    //just to have some member instances of T
    T member1, member2, member3, member4;

};

template<typename T>
const typename Vector4<T>::vec Vector4<T>::constVec = {&Vector4::member1,&Vector4::member2,&Vector4::member3,&Vector4::member4};

int main() {
    Vector4<int> v;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        (v.*Vector4<int>::constVec[i]) = 5;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I added one member of type T to my question. Would you mind adding some code, that shows the usage of `vec` together with member?

Comment: So, the moral of the example is that you can iterate through the members.

Comment: +1 Very nice. Thank your for the explanation and the example.